# "No such file or directory" error when scp from remote to local instance

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, git-bash

I am trying to copy a directory from a remote AWS instance to my local instance.

I have **not** ssh'ed into the remote instance unlike the user in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1204664/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-attempting-to-copy-using-scp-from-remot?rq=1&newreg=af53f9b9e7fb4322897f63c838dbc812)

I simply run the command:

```
scp -r user@remotehost:/path/to/dir/on/remote/instance /C:/Users/example/user/path/to/destination
```

I type the server password in

I then get the error message:

```
/C:/Users/example/user/path/to/destination: No such file or directory
```

relating to the local instance path

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: Using Gitbash on a local windows instance

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: From the tags you are using, I assume you are running the `scp` command from withing the Bash shell that comes with Git for Windows. Is this correct?

Comment: I am using gitbash within a windows instance

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the information I needed to answer. Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1407789/edit) so that the shell you use is more visible? And welcome to SuperUser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git Bash on Windows, disk names are lowercase and don't have colons.

So instead of:

```
/C:/Users/example/user/path/to/destination
```

In Git Bash, you should use:

```
/c/Users/example/user/path/to/destination
```

---

Alternately, in WSL (the preferred way to run Linux programs on Windows):

```
/mnt/c/Users/example/user/path/to/destination
```